# Blackberry internet services with exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, blackberry

I'm upgrading our network from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 and it's going swimmingly. Well it was, I've moved some users to the 2010 box with blackberries (iphones working fine) and I can't get it working with BIS (blackberry internet services)

Whatever settings I try I get a

> An error occurred during email account validation.
>   Please check your information and try again. 
>   If the error persists please contact your System Administrator.

error.

I'm using http://mail.mydomain.com/owa url, which works fine and the authentication settings I'm trying (username / password) work fine in owa.

Close to the point of pulling my hair out on this issue, is there a way to find out what it's failing on? Have I missed something very simple?

Tom

Comment: Are you using the `https://` secure URL?

Comment: I'm not no. Do I have to?

Comment: I typically do, but I also have redirects in place. Try the suggestions below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the http and https URLs?

Also see if  you can see the Exchange Web Services directory:

(input a username/password)

```
`http://mail.maildomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`
`https://mail.maildomain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`
```

You should get an XML page after successful authentication.

Comment: I've tried now with and without and it works (in owa) and EWS works fine, but EWS isnt the link that goes in BIS settings yeah?

Comment: No, that's not the link you'd use. Just a validation of your EWS directory accessibility. Did you try this without the "owa" portion of the URL?

Comment: Yeah I have. It's so frustrating it's unreal! Did you have to change anything in exchange?

Answer (score 1):

With 2010, from my experience, it has to be https://mail.mydomain.com/owa